# How do I embed in a text widget?

Tags: widgets, embed

I'm trying to embed a YouTube video in a Text Widget and Wordpress 4.0 is stripping out the embed when rendering.  For example, if I put this in the body of the widget:

```
Before
[embed]http://youtu.be/JQ_2De2cnzI&rel=0&showinfo=0&w=120[/embed]
After
```

then when I inspect the div in the browser I end up with this:

```
<div class="textwidget">Before

After</div>
```

How can I get Wordpress to keep the embed in the widget?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shortcodes are not supported in the Text Widget by default. Add the following to your functions.php:

```
// Enable shortcodes in WP Text Widget
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'shortcode_unautop');
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode', 11);
```

Instead of wrapping the video URL in the [embed] shortcode, use the following in the Text Widget:

```
[video src="http://youtu.be/JQ_2De2cnzI&rel=0&showinfo=0&w=120"]
```

For more info on the [video] shortcode, see the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Video_Shortcode).

Comment: That didn't do it: the embed is still not appearing.  Anything else that might be getting in the way?

Comment: Updated my answer. I'm not sure why the [embed] shortcode doesn't work in the Text Widget, but [video] works OK.

Answer (score 1):

The suggested code from @Gabriel do not work for me but this one do.

```
add_filter( 'widget_text', array( $wp_embed, 'run_shortcode' ), 8 );
add_filter( 'widget_text', array( $wp_embed, 'autoembed'), 8 );
```