# Static image for embedded YouTube video instead of blank player?

Tags: widgets, embed, youtube, video-player

Thanks to [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/166536/48996) I have embedded a YouTube video in a Text Widget using

```
[video src="http://youtu.be/JQ_2De2cnzI&rel=0&showinfo=0"]
```

However it displays as this blank player when the page is loaded:

[image: Blank YouTube player]

I've tried adding a `&start=1` to get it to show the first frame of the video but that doesn't have any effect.

How can I get this embedded player to show a still from the video instead of this blank player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding another attribute

```
[video src="http://youtu.be/JQ_2De2cnzI&rel=0&showinfo=0" poster="/path/to/image-placeholder"]
```

See the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Video_Shortcode)